# Discriminant of real cyclotomic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, normed-spaces, cyclotomic-fields, discriminant

I know following theorem (and its proof):

> Let $K\subset L \subset M$ be number fields, $[L:K] = n, [M:L]=m$, and let $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ and $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m\}$ be bases for $L$ over $K$ and $M$ over $L$, respectively. Then we have
>   $$\text{disc}_K^M(\alpha_1\beta_1,\ldots, \alpha_n\beta_m) = \left(\text{disc}_K^L\left(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\right)\right)^m N_K^L\left(\text{disc}_L^M\left(\beta_1,\ldots, \beta_m\right)\right)$$
>   where, for example, $\text{disc}_{K}^L(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) = \det(\sigma_i(\alpha_j))^2=\det(T_{K}^L(\alpha_i\alpha_j))$ where the embeddings $\sigma_i$ of $L$ in $\mathbb{C}$ fix $K$ point-wise; $N_K^L$ is the norm function defined for a number field $L$ which fixes $K$.

Using this I have to prove

> Let $p$ be an odd prime number, then $\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}(\xi_p) = p^{(p-3)/{2}}$, where $\xi_p = \zeta_p +\zeta_p^{-1}$ and $\zeta_p = e^{2\pi i /p}$.

I have observed that

1. $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}[\xi_p] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]$
2. $[\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]:\mathbb{Q}] = \frac{\varphi(p)}{2}$
3. $[\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]:\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]]=2$
4. $\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}(\zeta_p) = \pm p^{p-2}$, where + sign holds iff $p\equiv 1,2 \pmod 4$.
5. $\{1,\zeta_p,\xi_p,\xi_p\zeta_p, \ldots, \xi_p^{n-1}, \xi_p^{n-1}\zeta_p\}$ is an integral basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]$.

[Source of question: ex. 35, Ch 2, "Number Fields" by D. A. Marcus.]

Comment: Do you know integral bases for these extensions?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know that the integral basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]/\mathbb{Q}$ is $\{1,\xi_m, \ldots, \xi_m^{n-1}\}$ where $n=(p-1)/2$. But I'm not sure about the basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]/\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]$, I think it's $\{1,\sqrt{-1}\}$.

Comment: I would think that $\{1,\zeta_p\}$ is more likely. Why should $\sqrt{-1}$ even be an element of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, you are right. So, I can conclude that: $$\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}(1,\zeta_p,\xi_p,\xi_p\zeta_p, \ldots, \xi_p^{n-1}, \xi_p^{n-1}\zeta_p) = \left(\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}\left(1,\xi_p,\ldots,\xi_p^{n-1}\right)\right)^2 N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}\left(\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(1,\zeta_p\right)\right)$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Also in related problem I proved that: If $n=\frac{\varphi(m)}{2}$, then $\{\xi_m^i\zeta_m^j : i = 0,1,\ldots, n-1; j = 0,1\}$ is an integral basis for $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_m]$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hence, if $K=\mathbb{Q}, L=\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p], M=\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]$ then I can rewrite above expression in condensed form as $$\text{disc}_K^M(\mathcal{O}_M) = (\text{disc}_K^L(\mathcal{O}_L))^2  N_K^L(\text{disc}_L^M(1,\zeta_p))$$

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you have found the intended way to solve this exercise. Can you make it work?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Don't know how to handle: $N_K^L(\text{disc}_L^M(1,\zeta_p))$

Comment: I would begin that calculation with the observation that
$$m(x)=x^2-\xi_px+1$$
is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_p$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\xi_p)$. So, for example,
$$tr^M_L(\zeta_p)=\xi_p.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So I can write using transitivity of norm, $$N_K^L(\text{disc}_L^M(1,\zeta_p)) = N_K^L(N_L^M(m'(\zeta_p))) = N_K^M(m'(\zeta_p))$$ Yes it will be solved. Thanks.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry to disturb again, but I am not able to figure out how to compute  $N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}]} (1+\zeta_p)$.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_p$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, then $f(x-1)$ is the minimal polynomial of $1+\zeta_p$.  Alternatively, $1-\zeta_p$ and $1-\zeta_p^2$ are Galois conjugates, and $1+\zeta_p$ is their ratio.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  $\Phi_p(x-1)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\zeta_p+1$ where $\Phi_p(x) = 1+x+\ldots+x^{p-1}$, therefore  $N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}]} (1+\zeta_p)$ is equal to constant term in $\Phi_p(x-1)= 1+(x-1)+\ldots+(x-1)^{p-1}$, since $p-1$ is even we will have $\frac{p-1}{2}$ times $-1$ and $\frac{p-1}{2}+1$ times $+1$, thus leaving $+1$ as constant term. Hence $N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}]} (1+\zeta_p) = 1$.

Comment: Sounds right to me, it's a unit. Could you collect your calculations to an answer. That way A) we avoid extending this comment exchange, B) you get feedback about your entire solution, C) the question will no longer be unanswered, and last D) you also get reputation from the upvotes :-)

Comment: @rationalbeing Since there are plenty of greek letters, why in the same post and even in the same line would you to choose $\;\zeta,\,\xi\;$ ?? Why not to use something to *clearly tell them apart*, like $\;\zeta,\,\omega\;$ , or $\;\zeta,\,\phi\;$ , etc.?

Comment: @DonAntonio I apologize for wrong selection of symbols, will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on hints by [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen), here is the answer:

We know that, the integral basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]/\mathbb{Q}$ is $\{1,\xi_p, \ldots, \xi_p^{n-1}\}$ and the integral basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]/\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]$ is $\{1,\zeta_p\}$.

We will use above result to calculate discriminant:
$$\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}(1,\zeta_p,\xi_p,\xi_p \zeta_p, \ldots, \xi_p^{n-1}, \xi_p^{n-1}\zeta_p) = \left(\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}\left(1,\xi_p,\ldots,\xi_p^{n-1}\right)\right)^2 N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}\left(\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(1,\zeta_p\right)\right)$$

Keeping in mind invariance of discriminant of a ring of integers and using the observations stated in question we get (note that the $\pm$ signs cancel out on both sides)

$$\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}(\zeta_p) = \left(\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}(\xi_p)\right)^2 N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}\left(N_{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(f'(\zeta_p)\right)\right)$$
where $f(x) = x^2-\xi_p x+1$, is the minimal polynomial for $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]$ over $\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]$. Using transitivity property of norm we can re-write it as

$$\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}(\zeta_p) = \left(\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}(\xi_p)\right)^2 N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(f'(\zeta_p)\right)$$

Note that $\xi_p = \zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1}$, therefore

$$N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(f'(\zeta_p)\right) = N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(2\zeta_p-\xi_p\right)= N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(\zeta_p-\zeta_p^{-1}\right)=\frac{N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(\zeta_p-1\right)N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(\zeta_p+1\right)}{N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]}\left(\zeta_p\right)}$$

Observe that $\Phi_p(x-1)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\zeta_p+1$ where $\Phi_p(x) = 1+x+\ldots+x^{p-1}$, therefore  $N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}]} (1+\zeta_p)$ is equal to constant term in $\Phi_p(x-1)= 1+(x-1)+\ldots+(x-1)^{p-1}$, since $p-1$ is even we will have $\frac{p-1}{2}$ times $-1$ and $\frac{p-1}{2}+1$ times $+1$, thus leaving $+1$ as constant term. Hence $N_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}]} (1+\zeta_p) = 1$. We can use similar argument to calculate $N(1-\zeta_p)=p$. Using these we get (note that we already cancelled out sign arising due to $p$)

$$\text{disc}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]}(\xi_p) = \text{disc}(\xi_p) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{p^{p-2}}{p}} = \pm p^{\frac{p-3}{2}}$$

But + sign must hold since, $\mathbb{Q}[\xi_p]$ contains $\sqrt{\text{disc}(\xi_p)}$ (algebraic closure property of number field).